# use scipy.stats to automatically fit and use the parameter in pdf calculation

Tags: python, pdf, scipy

I would like my program to automatically choose the distribution that has the best fitness and use this distribution's probability density function to calculate the probability

1. Use `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit` to get the parameter of fitting, e.g.

   `paras = scipy.stats.norm.fit(data_array)`
2. Use `scipy.stats.kstest` to test the fitness

   `fitness = scipy.stats.kstest(data_array, paras)`
3. Choose the distribution that gives the lowest kstest score
4. Calculate the probability, e.g.

   `scipy.stats.norm.pdf(my_values, paras)`

I am not sure whether this is a rigorously correct way to choose the best-fit distribution. Currently it works well for normal distribution.

My problem is how to parse the argument to `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf()`. For some distributions there are three parameters calculated from `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit()`, including the shape, loc and scale. I tried to parse directly like

```
scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf(my_values, paras[0], paras[1], paras[2])
```

this will give me two values for pdf for one point.

I also tried to parse in this way

```
scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf(my_values, paras[0], paras[1], paras[2])
```

But the outcome is wierd. Does anybody ever want to do something like this and meet some problem of the same kind?

My goal is to replace the gaussian with any better distributions in the Naive Bayesian classification, in hope to improve the prediction accuracy.

Comment: If your main question is about how to choose the most "rigorously correct way to choose the best-fit distribution", rather than how to code the process up in `scipy`, you might be better off asking on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi @GeauxEric, did you ever solve this? I would like to do something similar (moving to sums of various distributions if simple distributions fail and final kernel density estimation). The answer to your variable parameter problem is to use `*paras` in the function call. Beyond that I'm thinking that a general and robust solution to this is not a trivial problem.

Comment: Hi @Ed Smith, I did not manage to solve the problem automatically. Since I found several distributions are enough to describe my model, I pass the arguments of those distributions manually.

Comment: Hi @GeauxEric, thanks for the reply. I think I'll end up with a similar solution...

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is how to parse the argument to scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf()

Interpreting this literally, it sounds like you are trying to use the `pdf` method of the [`scipy.stats.rv_continuous`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) class, but the `rv_continuous` class must be subclassed and instantiated before its `pdf` method can be used.

For the rest, I'm assuming you're using `rv_continuous` as a variable that refers to a SciPy distribution, e.g. `rv_continuous = stats.norm`. You may want to skip to the code at the end, but I will address each of the statements that indicates a problem first.

> I tried to parse directly like `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf(my_values, paras[0], paras[1], paras[2])` this will give me two values for pdf for one point.

It difficult to debug this without knowing what distribution `rv_continuous` refers to and what `my_values` is. If `rv_continuous` is a variable that refers to a SciPy distribution, if `my_values` is a scalar, if `paras` is the output of `rv_continuous.fit`, and if `rv_continuous` has three parameters (including `loc` and `scale`), there will only be one output, so the problem must lie in information not included here.

> I also tried to parse in this way `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf(my_values, paras[0], paras[1], paras[2])` But the outcome is wierd.

Since this is identical to the previous way, we would expect it to have the same behavior. Please consider elaborating on what the output is because "weird" can mean many things.

In any case, it sounds like this code will help. For each of two different distributions, it fits the distribution to data, creates a frozen distribution from the fitted parameters, and computes the PDF at a point. The two distributions have diffferent numbers of parameters, so you can see that the code works regardless of how many parameters the distribution has.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

rng = np.random.default_rng()
data = rng.normal(size=1000)

for family_name in ['norm', 'skewnorm']:
  family = getattr(stats, family_name)
  params = family.fit(data)
  dist = family(*params)  # note use of `*` to automatically unpack `params`
  print(f"{family_name}{params}.pdf(1): {dist.pdf(1)}")

# norm(-0.004263933560864075, 0.9864850754623957).pdf(1): 0.2408655741640401
# skewnorm(-0.9815681271426395, 0.660439450142722, 1.1895346103612483).pdf(1): 0.25093359040244
```